# SQL OR returns both expressions

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have a storred SQL Procedure where i want to join another table depending on the results of COALESCE or OR, but somehow it seems like coalesce is returning both expressions.

**Usecase:** If no schedule exists for a playlist -> return a default schedule (24/7). That works like a charme and i get the schedule with ID 1. But if there is a schedule the procedure returns both schedules. :-(

This is my code:

```
...
RIGHT JOIN schedule
ON COALESCE(playlists.ID = schedule.PLID,playlists.SCHEDULES_ID=1)
WHERE devices.IDENTIFIER = ParamID;
```

Any suggestions?

THX in advance!

Peter

**UPDATE**

It seems like coalesce isnt the right solution for my case. Does anyone have a suggestion?

I have a table "schedules" which has a column "PLID" (PlaylistID). In my query i want to join this table based on this value. If there is no schedule with a matching PLID, i want to join a default schedule (ID = 1).

**UPDATE 2**

I am now trying a new approach, which still doesnt seem to work. If there is no schedule, i get the default schedule (ID1). If there is a schedule -> i get default + actual assigned schedule (PLID = playlists.ID)

```
LEFT JOIN schedule
ON (schedule.PLID=playlists.ID) 
OR (schedule.ID = '1')
```

Comment: Er, that's not how using coalesce is supposed to work

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard, do you have any suggestions for my case?

Comment: Please rephrase it as a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this goes wrong as a join is because you have arranged it so that your join always succeeds when joined to your defaults and also sometimes succeeds when you join to your data..  but critically the join to the default data causes a different row than the join to the real data, so they aren't related rows any more

It's really hard to tell you why your query fails because you didn't include enough sample data but I'll try and invent some

```
playlists.ID  playlists.schedulesID  playlist.name
1             1                      default playlist schedule holder
2             100
3             null

schedule.ID  schedule.PLID  schedule.name
X            1              default 247 schedule                   
Y            2            custom schedule 100
Z            null           nully schedule


     COALESCE(playlists.ID=schedule.PLID,playlists.SCHEDULES_ID=1)
1,X  true on 1st argument, row shows
1,Y  false on 1, row hides
1,Z  null on 1, true on 2, row shows
2,X  false on 1, row hides
2,Y  true on 1, row shows
2,Z  null on 1, false on 2, row hides
3,X  false on 1, false on 2, row hides
3,Y  false on 1, false on 2, row hides 
3,Z null on 1, null on 2, row hides
```

Notice the truth set for the first one - two rows have a truth so 1,X and 1,Z show giving a "duplicate" row 1

Putting a boolean expression inside your COALESCE is something you can probably only get away with on mysql, maybe Postgres. Oracle and sqlserver wouldn't allow it. It's not exactly the cause of the problem though; the logic of providing a default is broken because it doesn't try to put the default values on the same line as the row, in case the row is missing

You'd be better off doing something like this:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(a.x, d.x) as x,
  COALESCE(a.y, d.y) as y
FROM
  tableWithAllRows a
  LEFT JOIN
  tableWithSomeRows s ON a.id = s.id

  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE ID = -1 --values in row is -1 are defaults
  ) d
```

Notice that here we specifically do the join with an outer so we tolerate missing data, then we use a cross join that will always succeed and ensure the subquery has only one row. This means every row in the outer join has a default row available. We use coalesce to pull the default values, not to do the join.

Edit; you seemed to indicate you didn't understand this so I'll give another example with a relation that's easier to understand

At home you have storage for food. Sometimes the storage is a cupboard, other times it is a refrigerator. Food items could have a defined storage location or a default one:

```
ID, Name 
1, Cupboard
2, Refrigerator

Food, Name, StorageID
A, Milk, 2
B, Cereal, 1
C, Beer, null
```

Milk goes in the fridge, cereal in the cupboard, beer is unspecified (we will default it). You're fine with this:

```
SELECT * FROM
  storage s
  LEFT JOIN food f ON f.StorageID = s.ID
```

Beer turns out null for storage because it has no StorageID set. You decide to default it going in the cupboard:

```
SELECT * FROM
  storage s
  LEFT JOIN food f 
  ON 
    f.StorageID = s.ID OR
    s.ID = 1 --default to cupboard
```

This works great for cereal because the StorageID = ID, oh and also the s.ID=1 is true too, but you can't have "more true" - OR is just true or true, both conditions are true for cereal so cereal comes once

```
B,Cereal,1,1,Cupboard
```

All is good for beer too. The StorageID is null so StorageID = ID is not true, but ID=1 is true:

```
C,Beer,null,1,Cupboard
```

So far so good! But it all falls apart with Milk:

```
A,Milk,2,2,Refrigerator --Milk goes in the fridge because StorageID=ID
A,Milk,2,1,Cupboard     --oh no
```

This Oh No row  appears because you said `ID=1` for the default- and you can see it's true! That row really does have id1, cupboard in it. Nothing about our ON clause prevents it from appearing. Maybe we could change the query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  storage s
  LEFT JOIN food f 
  ON 
    f.StorageID = s.ID OR
    (f.storageID IS NULL AND s.ID = 1) --default to cupboard if no storage id
```

It will work until you reach:

```
D,Wine,3
```

What is storage ID 3? No idea; it's not there in the table but the left join brings it. 3 isn't null either, so the row ends up looking like:

```
D,Wine,3,null,null
```

Now we're stuck. There isn't a way to resolve this because your earlier attempt to bring in the default did indeed bring a default value for beer, but it brought an extra value for Cereal that was a second row (not related to the first). We tried to squash it with adding more stuff to our ON but no matter what we do something will go wrong

Instead of using OR which will cause more *rows* in some cases, we need another JOIN to give us more *columns* and we will make sure those columns have values that we pick as defaults if the real data isn't there:

```
SELECT * FROM
  storage s
  LEFT JOIN food f 
  ON 
    f.StorageID = s.ID

  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM storage WHERE ID = 1) def
```

See how we added another join and then pulled just one row out of the storage table (the cupboard row). Cross joining it means it will repeat on every row.

The data now looks like:

```
A,Milk,2,2,Refrigerator,2,Cupboard
B,Cereal,1,1,Cupboard,2,Cupboard
C,Beer,null,null,null,2,Cupboard
D,Wine,3,null,null,2,Cupboard
```

See the defaults in the last two columns? Now we can use coalesce to try and get the assigned location first and the default location second:

```
SELECT COALESCE(s.Name,def.Name)
```

For Milk this returns refrigerator. For beer it first finds null, so it goes to the defaults and returns that.

And then you realise the beer and wine would be best in the refrigerator because after all this you need a cool one. Change the subquery to "where ID = 2"

---

Another complicated way to do this would be to use a pair of subqueries, one that provides real values for matched rows and one that provides defaults for mismatched rows, Union them together and then inner join the data to them. Inner now works because we have ensured the table on the right has a row for every row on the left

A third way to do this is to number the rows with the specific one taking precedence (lower row number) over the default one and then only take the "precedence 1" rows

By the way it looks like your schedules tables relates to your playlists on one set of columns and your playlists relates to your schedules on another set of columns. That is probably a really bad idea that will tie you in knots for a long time

Decide whether a single playlist has multiple schedules or a single schedule has multiple playlists. If multiple playlists have multiple schedules, break it down into two 1:M relationships with a playlistschedules table

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, I am still not sure how I should implement the whole thing now. I have posted an update above and tested another approach with "OR". Unfortunately this one does not work either. :-( 

If I don't have a schedule, everything works as intended and I get a default schedule with ID=1, but as soon as I create more schedules, the default schedule will be listed together with the new ones.

Comment: Which part of the answer did you not understand? I'll look to improve it. It would have been a lot easier to write an explanation that was relevant to your context if you had provided example data. I explained why you get the repeated rows with the OR solution (it's actually no real difference to the COALESCE solution that was mentioned first, despite the wonky "only-works-in-mysql" syntax in the coalesce)

Comment: I added another section to the answer, using a simpler data model than you apparently have. Check out the milk/beer bit

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That explanation was fu***** awesome! :-D

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this logic:

```
...
RIGHT JOIN schedule
    ON playlists.ID = schedule.PLID OR
       playlists.SCHEDULES_ID = 1
WHERE devices.IDENTIFIER = ParamID;
```

This will make a join happen if the IDs are equal, or, if not, if the playlist has a schedule ID of 1.

Comment: I still get both results with this solution :-( .